# copypaste rows based on criterea cell on googlesheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i know i have a really stupid problem but i really can't find the problem to fix it.
i made my script that will copy and paste the data rows based on a data cell "X" that i have in my sheet and it's working very well in my test version, but when i'm using it on my work sheet when i modify the criterea based cell " VALIDER COMMANDE" and the column where it's located, it's not working.
i don't understand why or where i have the mistake.
this is my code
thanks in advance

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("New Orders");

  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G6yWsj4QCH0uwCVZrH-EU1eFTigmmFT-Y5diOjbVMtc/edit#gid=149753574";
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var pasteSheet = ss2.getSheetByName("order formulaire1");

// get source range
var max = copySheet.getMaxRows().toString();

var range = copySheet.getRange(2, 1, max, 10);
var dataValues = range.getValues();

for (i = 1; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
    if (dataValues[i][9] === 'X') {
        pasteSheet.appendRow([dataValues[i][0],
            dataValues[i][1],
            dataValues[i][2],
            dataValues[i][3],
            dataValues[i][4],
            dataValues[i][5],
            dataValues[i][6],
            dataValues[i][7],
            dataValues[i][8],
            dataValues[i][9]]);

        var clearRow = i + 2;
        copySheet.getRange('A' + clearRow + ':J' + clearRow).clear();
    }
}

// get destination range
var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, max, 1);

// clear source values
Browser.msgBox('Commande Confirmer');
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `when i modify the criterea based cell " VALIDER COMMANDE" and the column where it's located, it's not working.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Moving Selected Rows to another sheet

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G6yWsj4QCH0uwCVZrH-EU1eFTigmmFT-Y5diOjbVMtc/edit#gid=149753574");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("order formulaire1");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("output sheet name")
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let oA = [];
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    if(r[9] === "X") {
      oA.push(r);
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContents()
    }
  })
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```